# Валидация строк в DataGridView перед закрытием диалогового окна

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Доброго времени суток, Господа. У меня есть `DataGridView` и обработчик на событие `RowValidating`, который делает `e.Cancel`, если строка, не проходит валидацию. Соответственно нельзя никуда перейти с этой строки, пока не исправить ошибку. Так вот.

Если открывать форму, где находится этот `DataGridView`, с помощью метода `Show()`, то после закрытия окна, `DataGridView` все равно сгенерирует событие `RowValidating`, и окно не закроется, пока не исправить ошибки в строке, которая не прошла валидацию. Это то, что мне нужно.
Но мне нужно открывать форму с помощью `ShowDialog()`, тоесть чтобы оно было диалоговым. И по каким-то не понятным мне причинам, `DataGridView` отказывается генерировать событие `RowValidating`, когда я закрываю уже диалоговое окно.

Как исправить проблему? Мне нужно как-то проверить прошла ли строка валидацию перед закрытием диалогового окна, и если нет, то не закрывать его. Я уже весь `DataGridView` обрыл в поисках получение строк, которые не являются валидными, но все безуспешно...

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

Собственно, нашел решение, но правда не такое хорошее, как хотелось бы. Итак, подписывается на событие `FormClosing` нашей формы, и пишем вот такой обработчик:

```
void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = !ValidateChildren();
}
```

где метод формы `ValidateChildren()` возвращает true/false в зависимости от валидации дочерних контролов...